# Get slice of string with check mark character with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I need to check if a '✔' is at the end of one of my strings (a span) and it's not working, it works with other characters tho.

so, i'm trying: `console.log(document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML.slice(-1));` and it shows empty space instead of ✔, but it works with other characters.

How can i get it to be ✔? or something like

```
var is_tick = (document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML.slice(-1) === '✔') ? true : false;
```

Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: you should specify the unicode value.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for your answer, how should i specify the unicode value? I already tried with === 'U+2713' and === 'U+2714' without any luck.

Comment: Post you HTML for span.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should trim text retrieved with `innerHTML`, most likely there are some white space characters. After that you can compare against unicode character or will work too.

```js
var is_tick = document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML.trim().slice(-1) === '✔';
//                                  remove white spaces ---^
alert(is_tick);
```

```html
<span id="my_span">
  Some string &#x2714;
</span>
```

Comment: However, this answer describes the problem instead of just giving a solution and is therefor more likely to give insight into the problem, also for future readers.

Comment: @Gazta this answer came earlier than the other one by ~2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This is your characters HTML unicode `&#10004` - This will help you.

```js
var is_tick = document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML.trim().slice(-1) === '✔';
alert(is_tick);
```

```html
<span id="my_span">
  Some string &#10004;
</span>
```